# Need help on autonumbering on Microsoft Visual 2008

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am new to this site and will attempt to be as clear as possible while posting my first question. I am using microsoft visual studio 2008 and I am attempting to type my first complete code for my c++ class that is online.

Our instructor has provided us a video showing us what to type in to sucessfully type out the code. However, when he presses enter, on the next line the next number is automatically completed for him. The function is similar to the auto-numbering feature in microsoft word. Where when one presses "Enter" a "B" pops up, when you press enter again "C." begins at the start of the line.

I have a link to the video that hopefully will work.

http://programming.msjc.edu/cpp/1Introduction.aspx#LiveTabsContent2686179-lt

I am fine until 2:30 on the video. This is when he presses enter, the number line just continues automatically. My software does not do that. :/

Thank you, any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: Can you show us your code ? It's easier to help you this way :)

Comment: At 20 minutes he shows how to turn on line numbering.

Comment: I have not written much code yet. The video around 4:00 minutes will give you an idea of what the code is supposed to look like. My problem is i am unable to get the numbers to automatically to come up. This is what I have so far.

Comment: Don't worry about line numbers.  The C++ language doesn't care about lines.

Comment: The line numbers aren't part of your document like they are in a Word document.  They're just visual aids for you as a programmer.  When you save it, the line numbers don't get saved with it.  Don't type the line numbers in yourself.